# Issues with React array mapping accessing information on click

Tags: arrays, reactjs, database

I'm building a data visualisation project with three.js and React.

Currently when you interact with the three.js sphere a click event is fired to get user and country data from a mock database.

This data is passed to my overlay component so it'll pop up on click.

It's all pulling through correctly but when it comes to mapping through the data I can't seem to access what I need.

Code below, any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm assuming I'm doing something silly!

```
import OverlayContent from "./OverlayContent";
import { onCountryClick } from "../Scene3D/AppSignals";
import Portal from "./Portal";
import "./style.scss";

class Overlay extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { overlay: false, users: [], country: [] };
    this.openOverlay = this.openOverlay.bind(this);
    this.closeOverlay = this.closeOverlay.bind(this);
  }

  openOverlay() {
    this.setState({ overlay: true });
  }

  closeOverlay() {
    this.setState({ overlay: false });
  }

  onCountryClick = (country, users) => {
    this.openOverlay();
    this.setState(
      {
        users: [...this.state.users, users],
        country
      },
      () => {}
    );
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.onCountrySignal = onCountryClick.add(this.onCountryClick);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.onCountrySignal.detach();
  }

  render() {
    const users = this.state.users;
    const country = this.state.country;
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div className="btn-container">
        {this.state.overlay && (
          <Portal>
            <div>
              {users.map(user => (
                <>
                  <h1>{user.nbUsers}</h1>
                  <h1>{user.name}</h1>
                </>
              ))}

              <button className="btn" onClick={this.closeOverlay}>
                Close
              </button>
            </div>
          </Portal>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Overlay;
```

So when clicking on the overlay, I just get empty  tags, the console log is showing...

````
overlay: true
users: (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
country: "USA"
__proto__: Object```

I need to access user.name, country and a few other bits of data.
````

Comment: change `{users.map(user => (
                <>
                  <h1>{user.nbUsers}</h1>
                  <h1>{user.name}</h1>
                </>
              ))}` 
to
 `{users && users.map(user => (
                <>
                  <h1>{user.nbUsers}</h1>
                  <h1>{user.name}</h1>
                </>
              ))}` if it dosent work, please provide a fiddle or stackblitz example

Comment: Hey @AkhilAravind thanks for that - I can now get the nbUsers to show, which is great. However when I then click on the next place I get the new nbUsers, along with the previous one. Is there a way for me to 'clear' the data on a new click event?

Comment: thats because you are appending new user list to the old one in your `onCountryClick` function, check here `this.setState(
      {
        users: [...this.state.users, users], // you are appending new to the old one//
        country
      },
      () => {}
    );`, change this to `this.setState(
      {
        users: [users],
        country
      },
      () => {}
    );`. Let me know your issue is resolved.

Comment: @AkhilAravind perfect that works thanks! Sorry just one more thing, the data doesn't seem to appear until the second or third click event. The first couple are just empty. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: can you create a stackblitz example for the same, I will resolve all queries there + code refactoring

Comment: Thanks @AkhilAravind thats kind of you to offer, unfortunately the project is literally fifty files and I don't think I can get it to a point where you can see it without adding them all in!